# Is there a way to set vertex color of selected vertices with single click?

Tags: vertex-paint

I have some objects that I want to set the vertex colors of.  While I can use my tablet to do this in vertex paint mode, for the project I'm working on, I just need to flood fill the selected vertices with my current color.

Basically, I want to set all vertex colors to black, then pick a few faces and set the vertex colors of those to bright red.  Is there a faster way to do this, or do I have to hand paint all the colors?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a way.

---

**Edit**

Actually, you can skip Edit mode.
One can also select vertices directly in Vertex paint mode and then "Paint -> Set vertex colors"

---

Tab into edit mode, and select vertices you want to affect.

[image]

Tab into "Vertex Paint" mode and select "Vertex selection masking for painting" (second icon to the right from "Vertex Paint" dropdown.

[image]

Choose color if already not set.

[image]

Choose "Paint -> Set vertex colors" with a *single click* :)

[image]

The color will only apply to the vertices that were selected in Edit mode.

[image]

Comment: After your choose color step, you can also press Shift + K to fill the current selection.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply the currently active vertex color for all vertices at once while in **Vertex Paint Mode**. Just select (**Paint** -> **Set Vertex Colors**) from the header menu. Basically, you set the dominant vertex color for the whole mesh and then manually paint a few vertices afterwards.

While this doesn't work on a selection but only the whole mesh, you might want to split/join your objects beforehand. So that you don't need to paint too much geometry by hand. But there might be some alternative approaches to this like working with vertex groups or utilizing the vertex weight. But this might be the more straight-forward solution.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You still have to go through some steps, but you can save yourself from having to paint the colors on in a tedious way.

Here a little explanatory video:
[image: Vertex color change]

It's with your words, "flood filling" all black first, then selecting only the faces you want red and setting their color as well.

Change to Vertex Paint mode and in activate paint mode, to select the color black.
Make sure the object is completely selected by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.
Then go under the menu "Paint" and use "Set Vertex Colors" (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to fill the entire object with black color, this will also generate a vertex color group for you.

Now before you do anything, change the color to the red you want to use later.
Changing in the selection mode, mark the faces to be turned red and either use the menu or the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> again. The selected faces should now be red while the rest is still black.

Comment: What if that menu item is grayed out? (inactive) :|

Comment: I didn't encounter a situation in which the menu items I used were inactive, could you elaborate more what you encountered please. Also, usually menu items are inactive if the operation can't be executed based on the current selection or mode. I would not be surprised if you found a situation I may never have encountered though.